# Cannot add a domain to existing drupal 7 site

Tags: ssl, domain-name, drupal, digital-ocean, drupal7

Sorry in advance if this is a dumb question, I can't seem to figure out how to add a domain name to a D7 site, (currently using an IP). The website is hosted on digitalocean, the new domain is from namescheap, and the site is Drupal v 7.41.

(The end goal is to apply a letsencrypt ssl certificate to the website, which is not possible without a domain name - so if anyone has better advice than bothering with the domain please let me know! SSL was implemented by following this step-by-step guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04)

The new domain has been added to digitaloceanl, and I've changed the `$base_url` variable in `settings.php` to the new domain. Trying to reach the site by the new domain returns the following Privacy Error warning:

"NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID"

And running tests on the ssl certificate return "MISMATCH,"

Both of which seem to imply the new domain is not working properly.

Not sure what other information to supply, so if anyone has a suggestion please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the full domain name, to connect when you get that error?  If you inspect the certificate, what domains does it show as being valid for?

Comment: Yes, and the certificate showing up seems to be for another domain... I've removed the certificate stuff for the old domain, but it's still showing in the browser...

Comment: Well first figure out if your DNS is correct.  Drop down to the command line on your system and use `nslookup yourdomain.example.org`.  Does it resolve to the ip of your server? If not fix that.

Comment: it is returning the right address :)